# Blocked on android phone, will my messages ever be read?

Tags: sms-blocking

Just to keep things short, I was blocked practically everywhere by someone.

I was drunk one night and sent some very very bad messages to this person via SMS!

I am just hoping that there is no change that they'd ever read it. I've read somewhere that Android pushes the SMS messages into a separate inbox, meaning that the person can view them one day if they access that inbox?

That would kind of defeat the purpose of the blocking feature a bit. I just hope they never get read!

If anyone can give me there 2 cents that would be great. Thank you.

EDIT: The phone in question here is a motorola phone, which I assume has very little bloatware (being close to stock android).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would entirely depend on the device, the SMS app, and its settings. For example, on Microsoft's SMS organizer app that I use, blocked SMS are stored for days before they are deleted.
The same is the case for most devices. Just like they will try to notify the user that a blocked number tried to call them, some apps may show a notification that a blocked number tried to text them. The others would keep the message and not notify. The remaining few would drop the message and neither save it, nor notify.

TL;DR: It will depend on the device and the SMS app used. You cannot do anything anymore. So, just hope that they never get to see it and move on.

Comment: The phone in question here is a motorola phone, which I assume has very little bloatware (being close to stock android). If so, do you know how many days the messages are stored for? (Yes, trying to move on... :( )

Comment: @noob If the app used by Motorola is Google's Android Messages app, then any messages from blocked senders are dropped. They will never get your message anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is we don't know if they will ever be read. Why we don't know?
Because it depends on whether the person to whom you sent the SMS decides to unblock blocked numbers or not.

When a number is blocked, the SMS are received but the messaging app (at least the standard that comes with most devices), put them in archives and doesn't alert or give notifications about them. However, they are present on the Message app. If the number is unblocked, then all those SMS will be available to read.